# restful POST in Play

Tags: java, playframework

I have been following some Play! framework tutorials, but I cannot get the simplest of examples to work.

```
String xml = "<thing><foo>first</foo><bar>second</bar></thing>";
Response response = POST("/thing", "application/xml", xml);
```

In my `/thing` method in the controller, the `Thing` object that is passed in is always `null`.

Does anyone have a code snippet that successfully POSTs a xml document to a controller action, and then ends up with a deserialised object at the end that can be persisted to the database?

Comment: Take the XML that is sent in the request and parse out the data you need to create the model object.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is an error in the [book](http://www.packtpub.com/play-framework-cookbook/book). The code `Request.current().params.get("body")` in the method `ApiPlugin.getXml(Class)` returns `String` object. There is no overloaded method `unmarshal(String)` in the interface `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller`. To make it works wrap that string into `java.io.StringReader`:

```
    String body = Request.current().params.get("body");
    return um.unmarshal(new StringReader(body));
```